# How to reset its position back to the origin when it reach the end of frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phaser-framework

This one of the phaser examples, what Im trying to do is to load the image again when it reach the end o the frame. Can somebody explain how to do this

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1500, 200, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });

function preload() {

    //  You can fill the preloader with as many assets as your game requires

    //  Here we are loading an image. The first parameter is the unique
    //  string by which we'll identify the image later in our code.

    //  The second parameter is the URL of the image (relative)
    game.load.image('Car', 'car.jpg');
}

function create() {

    //  This creates a simple sprite that is using our loaded image and
    //  displays it on-screen
    //  and assign it to a variable
    var image = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'Car');

    game.physics.enable(image, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    image.body.velocity.x=750;

    if (image>game.width)
    {
        game.load.image('Car', 'car.jpg');
        var image = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'Car');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the above is just pseudo code because there are lots of little errors. But there are a number of issues with this approach.

If you know what the new image needs to be in advance, then preload it up front and then use loadTexture to apply it:

```
function preload() {
    game.load.image('Car', 'car.jpg');
    game.load.image('Pumpkin', 'pumpkin.png');
}

...

function update() {
    if (car.x > game.width) {
       car.loadTexture('Pumpkin');
    }
}
```

Also some other things to watch out for:

1) Only change the texture if it's not already set (in the example above it will run loadTexture over and over, unless you reset the car.x coordinate)

2) If you can't preload the image up front, then you can load it during play. Look at the "Loader Events" example code for details.

3) You need to check the sprite position in `update` and not `create` (as it won't have moved at all by that point).